# How to create a menu in a ussd app with php

Tags: php, xml, ussd

Good day, I would like to create a menu for my ussd app, it's my first app so i'm still a little bit confused.
The only i was able to do so far is to display message on the screen that says "Welcome dear customer", but me I want to create an interactive menu.

```
<?php
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");

 /**
  * Here we receive the xml from the network company
  * 
  */
   $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
   $json_data = json_decode($json);
   error_log($json_data->param1);

   $xml = simplexml_load_string($json_data->param1) or die('Error: 
   Cannot create the object');

   $MessageType = $xml->MessageType;
   $ConversationID = $xml->ConversationID;
   $SessionID = $xml->SessionID;
   $TransactionID = $xml->TransactionID;
   $MessageString = $xml->MessageString;
   $MSISDN = $xml->MSISDN;
   $Success = $xml->Success;
   $IsFinal = $xml->IsFinal;
   $DateTimeReceived = $xml->DateTimeReceived;
   $MNO = $xml->MNO;

   /**
   *Here we create a xml that will send a message to the user
   * 
   * 
   */

   $option1 ='1.Welcome dear customer';

   $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<UssdMessage/>');

   $xml->addChild('MessageType', $MessageType);
   $xml->addChild('ConversationID', $ConversationID);
   $xml->addChild('SessionID', $SessionID);
   $xml->addChild('TransactionID', $TransactionID);
   $xml->addChild('MessageString', $option1);
   $xml->addChild('MSISDN', $MSISDN);
   $xml->addChild('Success', 'true');
   $xml->addChild('IsFinal', 'TRUE');
   $xml->addChild('DateTimeReceived', $DateTimeReceived);
   $xml->addChild('MNO', $MNO);



   echo $xml->asXML();
```

Answer (score 0):

The platform that converts the XML to SMPP must return some type of session indicator and with the MSISDN of the subscriber you can respond to the options that the user has selected.

We implement a finite state machine to support the logic of the menu.
Each operation is a state and in its definition you link to the next state in case of transition OK or in case of transition ERROR you respond a message to the user.

Within the SMPP protocol, the ussd_service_op parameter is usually used to determine if the response sent allows the user to respond or is a response that ends a user session.

The provider of the platform should give you the documentation referring to the bidirectional sessions and there should be the values for ussd_service_op.

I leave the link to the documentation of the SMPP protocol, you should read about submit_sm and deliver_sm http://docs.nimta.com/SMPP_v3_4_Issue1_2.pdf.
Sorry for my foreign english